# Laravel eloquent table structure

Tags: php, sql, laravel, relationships, eloquent

I am quite new to the `Laravel` and `Eloquent` world and I'm loving it so far, but I am having trouble understating how to structure my tables and models in order for me to be able to CRUD my data with eloquents relationships. So far I have structured my tables like this:

```
Users -----------------has_one------->onsite_teachers
onsite_teachers -------has_many------>train_lines
train_lines -----------has_many------>train_stations

train_lines -----------belongs_to---->text_train_lines
train_stations --------belongs_to---->text_train_stations
```

My question is how would be best to construct my models to me able to CRUD using the relationships. Because I have tried the following with no success:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->onsite_teacher->train_lines()->save($data);
$user->onsite_teacher->train_lines->train_stations()->save($data);
```

Comment: What didn't succeed? What you expect, what happens instead of that?

Comment: I think the documentation should provide you with enough information about how to set up your models, database structure, and how to save the data. http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#relationships

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query is wrong

Try this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->onsite_teacher()->first()
     ->train_lines()->save($data);
```